# How to crash web server via php

Tags: php, apache, nginx, server

I need to test the behaviour of some tool I use on my web server, but it works only in cause of server fault. So I need to crash the server by some way. I tested a lot of script found in google like: infinite loops `while(true)`, some `preg_match(...)`, `str_repeat(...)` functions - nothing crashes it) Even tried to retreive 8Gb file - no problems, php just says about `Internal server error`. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `apache` or `nginx`? your tags are for 2 different servers

Comment: Why not shut the web server down, and then try testing your tool?

Comment: What kind of behaviour are you trying to test for? If you really want to crash your web server (disclaimer: at your own risk. Only do it on your own hardware and not on your production machine), find out what server you're running (`apache`, `nginx`, etc) and the version number and find a nice DoS vulnerability with a proof-of-concept (E.g.: [Apache <= 2.0.44 (Linux)](http://www.exploit-db.com/papers/11/)).

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Actually I know that it's nginx, but as a heard it is based on apache... I'm not the administrator of that server

Comment: @MarkBaker That tool will run automatically. And I'm not an administrator of that server, I can't shut it down

Comment: If you aren't an administrator how will you bring the server back online? Are you mistakenly assuming that your PHP script will still run if you call it and it runs a command to start the server back up? And if its a cron job you'll probably have the admin rights to set up the cron

Comment: if you are not the admin on that server, how can you get your tool installed and working?

Comment: Administrators will run it again) And I know that this tool is installed there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be possible to get apache to segfault with mod_php by providing a regex that needs backtracking, setting high pcre limits and low php memory limits. I can't recall which versions where involved unfortunately.

Are you sure it's not good enough to just send a kill signal?

--edit--

That is send kill signal to your web server. Something similar to `killall -9 apache-httpd` or whatever the name of your webserver process is. Just check with your admin that this will target the correct processes.

Comment: thanks a lot. Can u please add some info? What exactly should I kill?